# CTAS query always gets NoSuchObjectException

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

I've opened this issue with Cloudera (https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/IMPALA-3278), but it hasn't gotten any response in months.   I'm hoping that someone here has run into this problem.

The issue is that any CTAS query I run always gets NoSuchObjectException - on the database name.  The problem spans multiple Impala versions, doesn't occur with any other queries, and the missing object that Impala complains about definitely exists.  For example:

```
Server version: impalad version 2.5.0-cdh5.7.0 RELEASE (build ad3f5adabedf56fe6bd9eea39147c067cc552703)
Query: use `testdb`
Query: create TABLE temp_fact_event AS SELECT col1, col2 FROM fact_event
ERROR: AnalysisException: testdb
CAUSED BY: NoSuchObjectException: testdb
```

This has happened with impala 2.2, 2.3 and now 2.5/cdh 5.7.  No other queries encounter this, and the database definitely exists.  Prefixing the table names with the database name has no effect.  And this happens with parquet & csv files, and with partitioned & non-partitioned tables.

Comment: Have you tried to invalidate metadata on the fact_event table before you select from it? The metadata may be out of sync with the actual reality of tables that exist in the database.

Comment: I have not tried that - however, all other queries against this table are working fine.  So, I don't think it can be stale metadata.